# Containers of inherited objects

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, abstract

I have a simple class structure

```
abstract class A {
List<A> containerList;
...
}
class B : A {....}
class C : A {....}
```

I make sure that the `containerList` contains only elements of class `B` or `C` (as the list is filled in these child classes and `A` is abstract).

Now, I'd like, somehow, to have a base property / method in `A` which would cast itself to whatever the real type of the object is, i.e. `B` or `C`. Having an abstract method is just fine, but it is important to get a `Collection<T>` of `B` or `C` objects, as I have bindings that will depend on it.

Comment: If you want `containerList` to only contain the derived type then you should consider making it generic.

Comment: Could You describe why Your binding depends on casting to appropriate inherited type? If You use base class You usually don't cast to specific inherited type later. Castings like this removes the abstraction and can make code harder to maintain.

Comment: I agree this shouldn't make any difference - the problem is that I use some reporting tool which binds to `List<A>` and doesn't use reflection to get properties of `List<B>`, so if I don't cast/convert, binding fails...

Answer (score 2):

> Now, I'd like, somehow, to have a base property / method in A which would cast itself to whatever the real type of the object is, i.e. B or C.

I think you're mixing *casting* and *converting*.  A Cast is a compile-time construct that just determines how methods and properties are bound at compile-time.  It does not change the underlying object.

There's no *conversion* necessary because the object is *already* either a `B` or a `C` - since `A` is abstract you can't have an object that is *actually* an `A`.

So a method that returns the underlying collection as either a collection of `B`s or `Cs` would just be:

```
public IEnumerable<B> GetBs()
{
    return containerList.OfType<B>();
}

public IEnumerable<C> GetCs()
{
    return containerList.OfType<C>();
}
```

If you want one generic method where the *caller* determines the type, you can do:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetTs<T>() where T:A
{
    return containerList.OfType<T>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use generics like that (though it looks a little strange):

```
public abstract class A<T> where T : A<T>
{
    protected List<A<T>> containerList;
    public Collection<T> ContainerList
    {
        get { return new Collection<T>(containerList.OfType<T>().ToList()); }
    }
}

public class B : A<B>
{
   //...
}

public class C : A<C>
{
   //...
}
```

---

But since `containerList` should only contain elements of the derived type, you can make it completely generic too like that:

```
protected List<T> containerList;
```

and could ommit the `OfType()` call:

```
public Collection<T> ContainerList { get { return new Collection<T>(containerList); }}
```

---

One drawback is that someone could have the idea to make a class `D` like that:

```
public class D : A<B>
{}
```

and would now have a class `D` with a `ContainerList` of type `Collection<B>`. But if it's that what he wants...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of casting the objects in the list, you could use the `is` keyword ([documentation link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx)). When you need to operate on your List, just ask before doing your operation `if (containerList[i] is B)`.